# Joining dataframes with same last letter as condition

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have 2 dataframes that I want joined.

```
product_no  code
12          aj
12          mn
13          aj

p_no       cde
12         *j
12         mn
13         *j

Result
product_no  code    p_no       cde
12          aj      12         *j
12          mn      12         mn
13          aj      12         *j
```

I want to match all codes that end with `j` with `*j` how do I do this? I know I have to join where `product_no === p_no`, but how do I join where if the last letter of a code is j, then join by `*j`?

**EDIT**

We are currently joining by `product_no`, and need to join the codes in the first dataframe to the codes in the second dataframe in an appropriate way.

The data for the second dataframe only contains 3 values for the `code` column: `2 letters, *j, or **` The conditions for the join are as follows:

1. If the actual code `mn` for example, exists in the second dataframe, then we join.
2. If the actual code is not in the second dataframe, then we check if the code in the first ends with `j`, if it does then we join where `cde` equals to `*j`
3. If the actual code does not end with `j` OR if we can't find `*j` in the corresponding dataframe, then we join by `**`

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what exactly you are trying to do. But if you want to join data frames on the condition [column last character] = *[column last character], you can use `substring` function as follows:

```
df1.join(df2, concat(lit("*"), substring(df1.col("code"),-1,1)) === df2.col("cde"))
```

Comment: Hmm sorry for the confusion. In the second dataframe that I have it can either contain the actual 2 letter code, `*j` or `**`. I'd like to join all the 2 letter codes present in the first dataframe. with the 2 letter codes in the second dataframe. If the 2 letter code is not present in the second dataframe, then we check if the 2 letter code in the first dataframe ends with "j" if it does, then we join it with `*j` If `*j`, Lastly, if the code in the first dataframe is not present in the second dataframe then we join it with `**` just like the result. Please let me know if this makes sense

Comment: Well, it's still a bit messy. I suggest you to update the question with clear requirements and an example that reflects them. For example it's not clear whether you want to join on `product_no` in all the cases as well.Whether `j` is a constant and only for `j` you want the functionality `j` =  `*j` or it's just an example and it should work for any character. Also what happens if you have a match with `*j` and also with `**`, both should be taken ? etc.

Comment: only for j and, if we have a match with *j only *j should be taken. I updated the question with more details